# Error while executing the pairs function in R

Tags: r

I am getting an error while executing the exact same code given in my textbook on my machine. It is the simple `pairs` function code.

my code is `pairs(college[, 1:10])`

The error I am getting:

> Error in pairs.default(college[, 1:10]) : non-numeric argument to
> 'pairs'

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Your `college[,1:10]` dataset contain columns that are not numeric.

Run:

```
str(college[,1:10])
```

And inspect the column types in your dataframe.

Since pairs matrix essentially creates a matrix of scatterplot using each combination of columns, it expect a dataframe with numeric columns only.

This makes sense, if you consider the fact that you wouldn't create a scatterplot using Student Gender (**a categorical variable, i.e non-numeric**) against Student Age for example. It doesn't make sense.

In your case, this error:

> Error in pairs.default(college[, 1:10]) : non-numeric argument to 'pairs'

Tells you that among the 10 columns, one or more of these are non-numeric. Either remove these columns in your call to `pairs()` or perform explicit coercion using `as.numeric()`.